# applying query on aggregation results in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in ES which has multiple documents. There is a field software_tags for which I wanted to have unique values. I applied term aggregation for that purpose as below:

```
GET /record_new/_search
{"size":0,
"aggs" : {
        "software_tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "software_tags.keyword",

                  "size" : 10000,
                  "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now once I have all the unique values, I want to use these values as a search functionality, as in, if we have software_tags with **"Windows"** word in it, I want that the user gets all those tags when he searches as any of such combinations as in:

> win, Windows, window, Window, windows

Kind of a search functionality. So basically I want to apply a case insensitive query to search on the aggregate results. How can this be done.

Comment: @IamIC  any help appreciated.

Comment: @syv help appreciated.

Comment: @Dennis please help.